# Record and play by clicking a buttom

Tags: javascript, android, audio, audio-recording

I have a code that plays a sound, records audio (by clicking one button) and plays the file recorded (by clicking another button). I want to know how to modify it in order to record and play the sound when I click the first button so when I click the second button I can heard the recorded sound that I played first.

That means: I want to know how to start record and play my audio file in record folder, both of them, only by clicking a button.

This is my code just now:

```
    public class MediaPlayerExample2Activity extends Activity {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";    
private static String mFileName = null;  
private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;    
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;    
private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;    
private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;
private void onRecord(boolean start) {       
     if (start) {          
     startRecording();        }
     else {           
     stopRecording();        }    }   
     private void onPlay(boolean start) {       
     if (start) {            
     startPlaying();        } 
     else {           
     stopPlaying();        }    }   
     private void startPlaying() {       
     mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();        
     try {            
     mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);           
     mPlayer.prepare();            
     mPlayer.start();        } 
     catch (IOException e) {  
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
     }    }    private void stopPlaying() { 
     mPlayer.release();       
     mPlayer = null;    }   
     private void startRecording() {
     mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
     mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
     mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
     mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
     mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     try { 
     mRecorder.prepare(); 
     } 
     catch (IOException e) { 
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");  
     }        mRecorder.start();   
     }    
     private void stopRecording() { 
     mRecorder.stop();       
     mRecorder.release(); 
     mRecorder = null;    
     }    
     class RecordButton extends Button { 
     boolean mStartRecording = true;  
     OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() { 
     public void onClick(View v) {                
     onRecord(mStartRecording);                
     if (mStartRecording) {                    
     setText("Stop recording");                
     } 
     else { 
     setText("Start recording"); 
     }                
     mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;            }      
     };       
     public RecordButton(Context ctx) { 
     super(ctx);            
     setText("Start recording");
     setOnClickListener(clicker);
     }    }    
     class PlayButton extends Button {
     boolean mStartPlaying = true;
     OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {                
     onPlay(mStartPlaying);                
     if (mStartPlaying) {                   
     setText("Stop playing");               
     } 
     else {
     setText("Start playing"); 
     }                
     mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;           
     }        };        
     public PlayButton(Context ctx) {            
     super(ctx);            
     setText("Start playing");
     setOnClickListener(clicker);
     }    }    
     public MediaPlayerExample2Activity() {
     mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
     mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";    
     }
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pru);
 mPlayer.start();

 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  
 mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
 ll.addView(mRecordButton,           
 new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(      
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 0));    setContentView(ll);   
 mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);


 ll.addView(mPlayButton, 
 new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( 
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 0));       setContentView(ll);    }

@Override    
 public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     if (mRecorder != null) {
     mRecorder.release();
     mRecorder = null; 
     }       
     if (mPlayer != null) {
     mPlayer.release(); 
     mPlayer = null;  
     }    }}
```

Thanks!! I hope you understand my question!!! ;)

Comment: Actually, I do not understand what you want. Do you want simultaneously play music and record smth using microphone? Or you just want to record smth and play it just after your recording?

Comment: at the "same" time: when I click on the buttom, I want to record and just later, play an audio file

Comment: I mean: play a sound and suddently open the microphone, just clicking one buttom.

Comment: So you want one button to be used in the following way: the first click on it will start recording, the second click on it will finish recording and start playing? Am I right? What should it do if I click on it third time?

Comment: In only one click, I want: first, start recording and, second, start playing. In the second click, I want to stop both tasks.

Comment: But you should somehow separate the events of recording and playing. So, for instance you can analyze the level of sound and if it calms down you can stop recording and start playing. So I think you should post a new question in which you can ask help for finding a library that can analyze the level of sound.